# False converted to null automatically in my PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I found in my code, when I pass a FALSE to a function. It converted to null immediately. I've read some articles knowing that False and null are equal. But I don't know when this conversion happens.

Below is my code

```
function equal($expected, $actual){
    if($expected == $actual) { //... }
}
function foo(){
    $signal = getSignal();
    equal(FALSE, $signal->good); //...
}
```

Comment: Did you tried '$a===$b'??

Comment: If you want strict equality checking - use `===`, otherwise data type conversion rules will be applied.

Comment: Not sure why people are down-voting a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use triple equal signs `===` for equality. For example

`false == null; // true`

`false === null; // false`

`0 == false; // true`

`0 === false; // false`

Check the docs on [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Remember to mark as solved when you can.

Answer (score -1):

No, they are NOT converted. You can `var_dump($variable)` at any time to see both the type and the value of `$variable` any time. But there are a few things which evaluates to `false` with the `==` comparison operator. So in fact `false == null` will evaluate to `true` just as `false == 0` or `false == "0"` in PHP. This is why the comparison operator `===` comes into the picture - using that instead of `==` in above example, all will evaluate to `false` instead of `true`.

For more information, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php